# In the diagram, given that $ADGB$ is an isosceles trapezoid, $CE = CD, BC = BD,$ $\angle AOD = 30^{\circ} $, prove that $BD = DF$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, angle

In the diagram, given that $ADGB$ is an isosceles trapezoid, $CE = CD, BC = BD,$  $\angle AOD = 30^{\circ} $,

> please prove that $BD = DF$.

[image]

My idea:
[image]
Or to prove $BD = DF$, only proving that $\angle DBO = 45^{\circ}$ would suffice.

Comment: You should know that the community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: @Blue ok, i will add my thoughts, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B, A, D, G, F are con-cyclic points of the red circle (centered at O).

[image]

Construct the green dotted circle passing through E, D, F such that:-

(1) DF is the common chord of the two circles;

(2) OM is the line of centers (where M is the midpoint of DF);

(3) $\angle EDF = 90^0$; and

(4) CE = CD.

All the above can be used to pin point AECF is a straight line with C as the center of the green dotted circle; EF as its diameter; and CE = CD = CF = its radius.

Since AECF is a straight line, $\angle 2 = \angle 1 = 0.5 \angle AOD = 15^0$

$\theta_3 = \theta$ [angles in the same segment]

$= \theta_1$ [$AD//BG$]

$= \theta_2$ [because of all the brown-marked angles.]

$= 2 \times \angle 2 = 30^0$ [angle at center = 2 times angle at circumference]

Therefore, $\angle ODF = \angle OFD = … = 45^0$